# How to bind MembershipUsersCollection to GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to populate a gridview using model binding. I have assigned to SelectMethod the following code:

```
public IQueryable<System.Web.Security.MembershipUser> GridView1_GetData()
{
  return Membership.GetAllUsers();
}
```

I know GetAllUsers() returns a MembershipUserCollection which implements ICollection and IEnumerable but I´m getting the following error: *'Cannot implicitly convert type System.Web.Security.MembershipUserCollection' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'*

I have tried using the following:

```
return (IQueryable&lt;MembershipUser&gt;)Membership.GetAllUsers().AsQueryable();
```

But I get the error *'source is not IEnumerable<>'*

I have found that I could do this:

```
GridView.DataSource = Membership.GetAllUsers();
```

But then I can´t use Model Binding. Any help here?

Thanks.

Comment: Try casting your asQueryable to a list: .ToList()

Comment: The MembershipUserCollection doesn't have that method. I have tried (IQueryable<MembershipUser>)Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>().ToList(); without luck.

Comment: This should probably work: GridView.DataSource = Membership.GetAllUsers().ToLi‌​st()

Comment: Ah ..you want to be able to modify the data in the gridview ? You might have to look into "objectdatasource" ..but it's been ages since i played with gridviews and the likes, so don't quite remember how that goes.. GetAllUsers() is probably already an enumerable since it works, you need a way to add that back to the database, just casting to queryable wont help there, it won't know what database stuff to call

Comment: btw: IQueryable<System.Web.Security.MembershipUser> GridView1_GetData() shouldn't that read IEnumerable<System.Web.Security.MembershipUser> GridView1_GetData()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MembershipUserCollection implements IEnumerable but not IEnumerable so we have to cast the result and then transform that in a IQueryable:

```
public IQueryable<System.Web.Security.MembershipUser> GridView1_GetData()
{
  return Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>().AsQueryable<MembershipUser>();            
}
```